# Number of arithmetic progressions

Tags: recursion, math, dynamic

Given N consecutive integers from 1 to N.

Count the number of ways to choose a number of numbers (at least 1 number) such that they form an arithmetic progression (AP) **modulo 1e9+7**

Define **L[N] is the answer**

The number of APs which begin with 2, end with N = The number of APs which begin with 1, end with N-1

The number of APs which begin with 1, end with N is the number of divisors of N-1 (=\tau(N-1))

So, **L[N] = L[N-1] + \tau(N-1)**

But **N <= 10^10** . The algorithm must be O(n), how can I calculate \tau(n)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `tau` (or `sigma0`) function ([look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)).

To find it, factorize argument value into primes. Value might be represented as

```
N = p1^q1 * p2^q2 * p3^q3 ... where p[i] are primes 2,3,5,7... and q[i] are corresponding powers
```

Then

```
tau(n) = (q1+1) * (q2+1) * (q3+1)....
```

For example,

```
60 = 2^2*3*5
tau(60)=3*2*2= 12 divisors  (1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30,60)
```

Factorization into primes (in `O(sqrt(n))` time) might be implemented quite simple - just divide by 2 while possible, then divide by 3 and larger odd values until sqrt(n), counting powers.

Comment: Calculating \tau(n) is a basic problem, L[n] is sum of \tau(n) as I have edited my post.